# Comparing string with an UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I have written the following procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLocationOfGuidPre] 
    @GuidArgument UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    .
    .
    .
    SET @SQL_String = 'INSERT INTO #Guids(FoundGuid) SELECT ' + @ColName + ' FROM ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = ' + @GuidArgument;
```

When I try to execute it, I get this error:

> The data types nvarchar and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator.

How can I compare a string value with `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`?

Comment: You need to use a guid literal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/literals-entity-sql#Anchor_10 (examples in the last section).

Comment: As you're cobbling together dynamic SQL, the requisite warnings about SQL injection apply. Even if all input is vetted, take care that identifiers (like column and table names) should be escaped using `QUOTENAME`, to prevent your code from breaking on unusual but legal names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried passing it as a parameter?

```
SET @SQL_String = 'INSERT INTO #Guids(FoundGuid) SELECT ' + @ColName + ' FROM ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = @GuidArgument';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_string,
                   N'@GuidArgument UNIQUEIDENTIFIER',
                   @GuidArgument = @GuidArgument;
```

Comment: Tried. This won't help because the error is called because of line where I setting SQL_String variable.

Comment: @Chyu . . . Notice the difference between this SQL statement and yours.  `@GuidArgument` is not put into the string.  It is passed as an argument.

Comment: That was the one! Thanks a lot, Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for this error is pretty clear: it says `+ ' = ' + @GuidArgument;` does not work, since you try to add an unique ID to a varchar... just try to cast your `@GuidArgument`as varchar and it should work.

Comment: If you try to cast **UNIQUEIDENTIFIER** into a **NVARCHAR**, it will take only few first signs.

Comment: Hm... strange: I just tried the following in a dev environment and it returned the correct varchar string: `CAST(y AS VARCHAR(200)) GUID_Char` (where `y` was my GUID column... so I guess "only the first few signs" isn't correct at all!